# Could you, please, tell if I could use Tor in this specific case?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, configuration, onion-routing

- could you, please, help me?

I used to use Tor all the time for visiting http://www.AirBnb.com - if felt much more safe that way because of all credit card payments for my bookings.

But now AirBnB updated their website - and with this new version using Tor seems not possible anymore. The new site simply doesn`t allow me even to log in my account.
 (Check it yourself if you can!)

Any solutions?..

Can I overcome this by changing any of the Tor settings? 
(I`m a noob, unfortunately)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Be aware of what Tor is and what it is not! Using Tor does not make it harder to snoop on your traffic. It just makes it harder to target you specifically. If you don't mind that your ISP knows that you use AirBnB and that AirBnB knows where you are, then Tor probably doesn't help you.

Comment: I am not much of a computer geek - but I think you might have trouble logging into any site that requires cookies using TOR - like Facebook, instagram etc.
I don't think you can access your account on any site, since the site doesn't "recognize" you. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not login because of a JavaScript issue, or are Tor exit nodes blocked? If its the latter, a VPN is the best solution for you. Get a cheap VPN (stay away from free ones) and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.   Re: "Can you not login because of a JavaScript issue, or are Tor exit nodes blocked?" -
Again, I`m a total noob, but I have a sense it`s both. 
When I`m pressing "Log in" button, nothing happens, the window wouldn`t show up - looks like JavaScript issue, right?.. -
but, besides that, trying to reach ANY other page of the website gives a "503 Service Unavailable" Error.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites like google that make life hard for Tor users, but usually the problem lies with extensions.  AirBnB seemingly works from my FireFox with HTTPS Everywhere installed, so the problem probably lies with NoScript.

I'm hesitant to recommend this, but you could try running TBB with NoScript extension disabled temporarily.  Actually TBB might be smart enough not to let you do this.  Just remember whatever changes you make to TBB extensions configurations, so that you can undo them later.

You might also write AirBnB a nice email saying you'd like to be able to access their site from TBB, maybe they'll fix it and add TBB to their Q&A process.